# ERROR : service 'environment' must be a mapping not an array

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.4.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
```

I try to up this docker-compose.yml file but it return this error

```
ERROR: In file 'C:\Users\ozan8\IdeaProjects\spring_examples\spring_elasticsearch\src\main\resources\docker-compose.yml', service 'environment' m
ust be a mapping not an array.
```

Comment: have you read the error carefully, it gives you a useful information

Comment: Your yml file is wrong, `environment` needs to be a property of the service `elasticsearch`, your identation is wrong. Follow the [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your yml file is valid and in the right location as the comment said

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 
      elasticsearch:7.4.2 
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```